Making sense of NAND latch circuit diagram
I'd like to build the push-ON-push-OFF latching circuit with two NAND gates described on this page:

But even before I start breadboarding it, I can't figure out:

Where is Vin supposed to go? Left side of the upper 100k resistor?
Should the inputs on both NAND gates really be connected respectively together? Am I missing something, or what is the point in using NAND gates at all, won't they just function as NOT gates if both inputs are high or low at the same time?


what is Vin ? ..

@jsotola the power input. The counterpart to Vout.

the switch is the counterpart to Vout ... are you talking about Vcc, which powers the IC?

Yes, that's what I meant. I was confused because the diagram has no other pins drawn for the NAND gates, so I didn't know where power was actually coming from.

logic diagrams do not always show the power supply pins ... refer to the datasheet for pinout ... or look at these https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cd4011+pinout&iax=images&ia=images

I think perhaps the label Vout is the source of confusion, arguably it's signal out.

@Victor Stanciu, I composed this story with great enthusiasm in my answer, specifically for you. Unfortunately, I don't have access to a computer right now to draw the initial schematics and renumber the following ones, but I will do so tomorrow. I published my answer in this unfinished state to give you at least a rough idea of the problem.

What we need to understand circuits

Where is Vin supposed to go?

A question that may appear trivial at first glance, but it actually conceals a deep philosophical underpinning – the philosophy of latches and flip-flops. This underlying philosophy is essential for comprehending specific circuit designs such as the one we are examining. However, it is a subject that is often overlooked or inadequately covered in traditional textbooks.
How to develop a philosophy for understanding circuits
The answer is simple – with a lot of thinking, comparing, and contrasting, we seek the common idea in specific circuit solutions. However, this requires thinking... a lot of thinking... For comparison, I have been pondering this problem since the 70s when I was a student, while you have been doing it for a week. But I will save you those 50 years by telling you this story. Here  I will trace the idea behind this original circuit solution by using a six-step CircuitLab scenario. For simplicity, I have used DC simulations, but they do not fully represent circuit operation. Maybe in the future I will also add time-domain simulations.
How to make the simplest non-inverting  latch
The recipe is extremely simple and intuitive - we connect the output of a non-inverting amplifier (a 1-input logic gate or buffer BUF) to its input. Thus, we force it, with the help of "self-reinforcing positive feedback" to maintain (remember) its output voltage in one of two possible values - 0 V (logic 0) or 5 V (logic 1).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
How to control the simplest latch
Now, we need some way to toggle this most basic memory cell (switch between its two states). This is typically done by applying a voltage to the input. But what is the input here, since the output and input are connected? They are one and the same. Obviously, with this "brute force" method of control, a conflict can arise between two voltage sources, the input voltage source and the buffer's output, when they have different voltages. Interestingly, however, this method is widely used in SRAM memories.
Vin = 5 V: For example, to switch the circuit to the "1" state, we can apply 5 V through an SW switch. But at the same time, its output may be in the "0" state, and then a "short circuit" will occur. Fortunately, however, the circuit will switch instantaneously to the "1" state and the "short" will disappear. The input source only needs to be "stronger" than the buffer's output to overpower it.

simulate this circuit
Vin is disconnected: Once we have switched the latch to "1", we need to leave it alone to remember the data stored in it. To do this, we need to remove the input source because it would keep the latch constantly in the "1" state and we would not be able to change its state to "0" by another input signal.

simulate this circuit
Vin = 0 V: Conversely, to set the circuit to "0", we apply 0 V. The output can be already at "1", and that is again "short circuit". But the circuit will quickly switch to "0", and the "short" will disappear.

simulate this circuit
Vin is disconnected: As above, once we have switched the latch to "0", we need to leave it alone to remember the data stored in it. Again, we remove the input source because it would keep the latch constantly in the "0" state and we would not be able to change its state back to "1".

simulate this circuit
Implementation
By two SPST switches: So, our simplest latch has a total of three states - two short ones where it is connected to the input source, and one long one where it is disconnected from the input source. We can implement it with two SMPT switches, one of which is connected to 5 V and the other to 0 V (or with one switch with neutral middle position).
By two cascaded NOT gates: But, as you have noticed, this is not the generally accepted way to control a device using a continuously connected input voltage source with two values. To solve this problem, they were forced to connect (cascade) two 2-input NAND gates in a loop and control this RS flip-flop with two separate input sources. Like the previous circuit, this one also has three states - a short "0" on one (S) or the other (R) input for switching to the corresponding state, and two "1"s for disconnecting the circuit from the input sources.

simulate this circuit

Am I missing something, or what is the point in using NAND gates at all, won't they just function as NOT gates if both inputs are high or low at the same time?

In the classic RS flip-flop, the two inputs of the NANDs must be separate because this allows for "unidirectional" (only with "0") control. When they are in "1", the inputs are "off" (they do not affect the circuit).
In your circuit, simple 1-input NOT gates must be used to control it with only one input voltage source (see the explanations below).
How to make a T flip-flop
Of course, a more obvious reason to make flip-flops using NOT gates is that they are more common and technological. But in your case, there is a much more valid reason for this. Let's see what it is like.
The problem
The task is to alternately toggle a latch by pressing a simple SPST button, i.e., to make something like a T flip-flop.
Basic idea
We can borrow the trick by which a D flip-flop is made into a T flip-flop - at the input of the D flip-flop, the inverse value of the current input voltage should be waiting. So the question comes down to having that inverse value.
Implementation
Vin = 5 V: So if the button outputs 5 V, the next (inverse) value should be 0 V.

simulate this circuit
Vin = 0 V: And accordingly, if the button outputs 0 V, the next (inverse) value should be 5 V.

simulate this circuit
Vin = Vout: Aha, that is why we need NOT gates - because we can take the inverse of the input voltage from the output of the first NOT1 gate! So we simply connect the switch between the forward and inverse terminals of the latch.

simulate this circuit
Adding a capacitor memory
But a new problem arises - when the button supplies the reverse voltage from the output of NOT1 to its input, it instantly starts to change in the opposite direction and the gate will not be able to switch at all. Then let's temporarily store the NOT1 output voltage across a capacitor C.
Now, when the reverse value is "1", the capacitor is charged to 5 V. When we push the SW button, a logic "1" is applied to the latch.

simulate this circuit
Conversely, when the reverse value is "0", the capacitor is charged to 0 V. When we push the SW button, a logic "0" is applied to the latch.

simulate this circuit
Just maybe the time between two button presses should not be too short for the capacitor C to recharge.
About the NAND inputs

Should the inputs on both NAND gates really be connected respectively together?

Yes, in your "T flip-flop" , the two inputs of the NANDs (especially NOT1) must be joined because this allows for "bidirectional" (both with "0" and "1") control.
Adding a capacitor reset circuit
A problem is that this "push-button T flip-flop" has an undetermined initial state. We can solve it by connecting another but smaller RC integrating circuit to the input of NOT1. It outputs a short "0" when the power is turned on.

simulate this circuit
Summary

The simplest memory cell (latch) can be made by connecting a logic buffer's output to its input. The self-reinforcing positive feedback holds it in one of its two possible states 0 V (logic 0) or 5 V (logic 1).

The simplest way (that is widely used in SRAMs) to toggle this memory cell between 0 and 1 is by briefly applying 0 V or 5 V to its common input/output. This can be made by a push-button (as in your circuit) or a pass-transistor as in SRAMs.

With this crude control method, a conflict can occur between the input voltage source and the buffer output if they have different voltages; so, the input source must be more robust than the buffer output to effectively override it.

After it has done its job, the input source can be removed because the cell continues to remember.

Thus, a latch requires a third, "idle" state where the input source is isolated from the common input/output pin.

In your specific "man-controlled  circuit" , this idle state is achieved by releasing the push-button. Today we would call this a "high-impedance state" (i.e., the button adds another high-impedance state to the existing 0 and 1 states).

In classic flip-flop circuits, the disconnecting of the input source is achieved by adding another 2-d input to the logic gate (using a 2-input NAND). Now, only the zero level is active; the 5 V level is inactive.

This requires adding another logic gate (another 2-input NAND) after the first one so that the latch can be toggled back by its second input. The result is the classical configuration of two cascaded NANDs in a loop (often drawn as two cross-coupled logic gates).

Your T flipflop configuration needs the NAND's inverted output for another reason - to change alternately its state. But it does not need 2-input NANDs; so it can be implemented by 1-input NOT gates.

The NAND1's inverted output is used as a next input signal. It is temporarily stored in a C1 capacitor memory.

The circuit is initially set by another smaller R2C2 integrating circuit.



Wow this is amazing, I have no words, thank you very much! Can't wait for the rest of the schematics!

@Victor Stanciu, Appreciate the feedback! I'm gonna finish up this incredible story about memory circuits as soon as I get home.

The input to the circuit is the switch.
Take the case where when first powered up the inputs to the first gate are low. This will make that gate's output high, and the second gate's output will then be low. That low is fed back through the lower 100k to the input, helping to keep the circuit in this state.
The high output of the second gate is fed back through the upper 100k resistor to the 1uF capacitor, charging it.
When the switch is momentarily closed the charge on the capacitor makes the input of the first gate high, it's output low, and the output of the second gate high. So now all of the polarities are reversed and the capacitor will be held discharged by the first gate's low output, when the switch is pressed again this low goes to the input, and everything flips back to the way it originally was.

Awesome, thank you!


Am I missing something, or what is the point in using NAND gates at all, won't they just function as NOT gates if both inputs are high or low at the same time?

Correct.  The circuit will work the same with two inverters, or one inverter and one NOR gate with all inputs tied together, or, or, or ...  There are many combinations of logic elements that will work in this circuit.  The only requirement is that both elements are inverting.
The lower right 100K resistor is the positive feedback path that creates the latch function.  The upper left 100K resistor is the inverted feedback path that causes the circuit to toggle.


Supply goes nowhere in the picture.

Those are two arbitrary NAND gates, that are just drawn as logical symbol elements without physical power supply pins. If they are two separate parts, both have their own supply pins. If it is a part with four NAND gates, all those four gates will have one set of supply pins.
If you use the CD4011 part, you connect to the supply and ground pins of the CD4011.

Yes they should be together as otherwise the NAND gate would not work, or at least the unused input would need to be tied high for the circuit to work. The NAND gate is simply used as an inverter. Yes you could use an inverter instead.

People, especially hobbyists, tend to use parts available to them, or what they already have. So wherever you took that schematic, the person happened to use a NAND gate.

Ahh, so the initial state of the A/B pins on the NAND gates is low, since there is no power connected directly to them. But then the leftmost NAND gate inverts this and outputs high on its output pin, which then gets fed into the other gate, and so on, and that's where power to the pins (and the rest of the circuit in the diagram) comes from? I was so confused as to what the NAND gates actually compare with no obvious power source.

Vin is the power input to the 4011 IC.  It is not shown on that schematic as it is assumed that you know you have to apply power to the Vcc pin of the IC to make it work.

@VictorStanciu No, the power supply connects to chip power supply pins that are omitted from the drawing.

You will have to consult the datasheet for the IC you are using to determine what pins are Vcc and Ground - then connect your power supply to those pins.

This latch is a pair of cross-coupled inverters. The switch feeds back the first inverter to the input to make it toggle.

Where is Vin supposed to go? Left side of the upper 100k resistor?

There is no 'Vin' from the outside. The first gate is being driven by feedback from Vout.

Should the inputs on both NAND gates really be connected respectively together?

Yes, there's nothing wrong with this, since we're using the NAND as an inverter. You could also tie one of the inputs to Vcc and do the same thing.

Am I missing something, or what is the point in using NAND gates at all, won't they just function as NOT gates if both inputs are high or low at the same time?

You could replace the NANDs with inverters. The reason for using NAND is that they come 4 to a package (for 74xx00 type), and oftentimes other parts of the circuit will want the NAND function.
However... there seems to be a problem with this circuit. If the button is pressed long enough, the latch begins to oscillate. Try it here and see what you think.


If the button is pressed long enough, the latch begins to oscillate.

In my case, that's actually a feature. This whole thing will go inside an arrow nock to light an LED. I plan to use a reed switch for the switch part, and making the LED blink by holding the reed switch longer in the magnetic field is just fine. I assume I'll be able to control the blinking rate by playing around with the RC time constant.

PS: I know the quadruple NAND IC won't fit in a nock, now that I understand what the NAND gates do I plan to just use a very small double NOT gate.

"This latch is a pair of cross-coupled inverters"... Could it be that they are not cross-coupled?

Uh, that's exactly what it is. Input to output, input to output, forms a positive feedback loop that self-reinforces the stored state.

@VictorStanciu:  Note that you WILL have to use a battery of some sort for this (or any) circuit to work.

@victor-stanciu I had better results if I used a separate inverter-buffer to feed back the inverted output to the switch input, since the first inverter tends to misbehave. You can edit the sim I posted and play with it. Try this for example: tinyurl.com/2xvtc5sb
